# Opening Files inside of a Folder in Python

Tags: macos, pygame, python-3.6

I am writing a program that allows the user to associate "tags" to specific pictures or documents.

Ex. "A family picture" and a "Friends Picture" are in the same file. The user wants a list of all pictures associated with their family. Instead of opening the Friends Picture it would open the Family Picture.

When the program opens I want it to open all the files one by one allowing the user to associate the desired tags. How can I go about having the computer open multiple documents one at a time with the fact that none of the files have the same name? I would like to avoid hard coding it as it would be near impossible, to my understanding.

In the code example below you can see that `var_a` is being used to name the window the same as the picture and also try to have the computer search for the users desired picture/document. Because you can't use variables in directories I have no clue what to do now.

```py
import pygame

var_a = input("Whats the name of the picture/document")

window1 = pygame.display.set_mode((1370, 750))

pygame.display.set_caption(var_a)

image1=pygame.image.load("/Users/verdenstudent1509/Desktop/Computers/FRC Game/var_a")

window1.blit(image1, (1370/3, 750/3))
pygame.display.update()
```

I expected the program to open the file that I typed into the input as `var_a` but instead, I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):File "/Users/verdenstudent1509/Documents/(PhotoLibraryUTO).py", line 9, in 
>    image1=pygame.image.load("/Users/verdenstudent1509/Desktop/Computers/FRC Game/'var_b'")
>   pygame.error: Couldn't open /Users/verdenstudent1509/Desktop/Computers/FRC Game/'var_b'

Comment: `image1=pygame.image.load("/Users/verdenstudent1509/Desktop/Computers/FRC Game/" + var_a)`

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize how simple that was going to be lol. Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

The name of the file is not `"var_a"`, the name of the file is the content of `var_a`.
[Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) can be concatenated by the `+`-operator:

```py
pathname = "/Users/verdenstudent1509/Desktop/Computers/FRC Game/" + var_a
```

I recommend to [handle the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), which may occur if the file was not found, because the filename is wrong, by a `try`-`except` statement:

```py
try:
    image1=pygame.image.load(pathname)
except:
    print(pathname + " is not a file")
```

Answer (score 0):

First define the folder path.

For example:

```
 f = "/Users/zaidahamed/croppingImage/output"
```

Then use a for loop to access each image and perform action on each one of it.
For example, i am trying to crop the image from the center to have 12x12 cm cropped image as output.

Code example:

```
  for file in os.listdir(f):
        # open 1 image 
        f_img = f+"/"+file
        img = Image.open(f_img)
        
        # perform action
        im_new = crop_center(img, 1050, 1050)
        
        # save changes
        im_new.save(f_img, quality=100)
    
    print("Crop success")
```